# How to get only domain name from email ID in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, parsing, substring

I have email ID's in a column, I want to get only domain name.

For example: I have `apple@hp-dell.com` or `asus@lenovo.com` and I want only `hp-dell`, `lenovo`.

Can someone please help with this in SQL Server?

Comment: What about if you have `'apple@support.dell.co.uk'`? How about `'Jane@marketing.hp.org'` or `'steve@sales.lenovo.org.us'`? You can't assume with an email address that the first delimited value after the `@` is the domain, nor the penultimate one.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(@email, 
                 CHARINDEX('@', @email) + 1, 
                 LEN(@email) - CHARINDEX('@', @email) - CHARINDEX('.', REVERSE(@email)))
```

Comment: Try this where `@email` has the value `Jayne@google.co.uk`. It will not give the wanted result.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
declare @email nvarchar(200)
set @email = 'xx.test@testmine.abc.com'
declare @startIndex int
declare @endIndex int
select @startIndex = charindex('@', @email, 1) + 1
select @endIndex = len(@email) - (charindex('.', reverse(@email) , 1) -1)


print @startIndex
print @endIndex
print substring(@email, @startIndex, @endIndex - @startIndex) -- will print testmine.abc
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a directory from the top levels of domains - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Internet_top-level_domains
Then solve your problem through the REPLACE() function.